How to deal with Anylogic Error in Split Block
I am currently modelling a brewery process with four different types of beer. In the cooling process i have two parallel coolers and I want to split the liters contained in the order to the two coolers, based on the capacity of the coolers and the different speeds. For that i am using a split and a splitfunction. When i simulate it though I get an error for the split (enclosed in screenshot). Where does this root error come from and how can I solve it? The type is an attribute contained in the order which implies which type of beer is being processed.




pls share the properties of the Split block. Hard to help without seeing where the error comes from... Also, you may want to consider using the Fluid library, by the sounds if it. Some tips to help us help you: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

I added them :)

As your error message says, the error comes from your source object, not from your split. In AnyLogic simulations, root usually refers to the Main agent.
If type is an attribute of the agent type that you are creating with the source, then you want to call agent.type instead of this.type.
this refers to the Main (or root) agent in this context.

I never call this.type though. How can I find where that comes from?

show us your Source block then :)

I have figured out the solution: It was a parameter I defined in the main, that was accessing the root in the wrong way. Thank you everyone for your help!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
